# How to detect if file in IDE is being edited using Open Tools API

Tags: delphi, ide, opentools

I made a small IDE plug-in using Open Tools API that accesses ClearCase. It has menu items "Check In", "Check Out", etc. It works OK but I want it to check out a read-only file automatically if I start typing in IDE editor or if I attempt to save the file. Do you think this is possible?

I tried a few things but gave up eventually. IOTAEditorServices.KeyboardServices has AddKeyboardBinding method which looked promising. Using it I added a notifier with binding type btPartial (and later tried btComplete) and the plug-in started detecting some shortcut key presses but not all keyboard events, far from it... Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I'd love to see your code. I've just asked a similar question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670621/how-to-hook-a-method-to-the-edit-event-in-delphi-7-ide

Comment: @neves: You'd better focus on [TOndrej](http://stackoverflow.com/users/11480/tondrej)'s [answser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/909485/744588) below. Presumably, `user112365`
is no more alive and kicking on SO.

Answer (score 8):

I think a "cleaner" way is to hook up a `IOTAEditorNotifier` to each editor and have your `IOTAEditor.Modified` method called by the IDE whenever the contents of the editor is modified, whether by keyboard, mouse or programmatically from another plugin.

[Here](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/17217)'s an example which registers an `IOTAIDENotifier` to be notified of files being opened in the IDE so it can register its `IOTAEditorNotifier` instances.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sounds like this should work. I'll give it a try and let you know later, most likely on Friday.

Comment: @user112365 Did you ever figure this out? I tried this but the problem is that Read-Only files cannot be modified. So the IOTAEditor.Modified is never fired.

Comment: @santiagoIT I think you can remove the read-only flag from the edit buffer even if the file itself is read-only.

Answer (score 1):

I must be possible somehow: we use SourceConexion (http://www.epocalipse.com/scx.htm) here, which auto checks-out the file before you edit the source or change the form.

JVCS has IDE integration support, it is open source, maybe they have implemented this too:
http://jedivcs.sourceforge.net/